# bootstrap 3.0.2 navbar navbar-collapse auto close all on click and touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a site built primarily for mobiles and so I've implemented the inbuilt bootstrap navbar-fixed-top with the hide/show toggle to display on mobiles.

The issue on my menu page i am using anchor links in the menu to jump down to certain sections on the page. When the anchor links are clicked the dropdown menu auto closes however the main nav bar does not close.

I want it so that when any link with in a drop down is clicked the entire menu is closed.

Also at the moment one of the anchor link is clicked under the menu section of the dropdown only one linked can be clicked, when another link is clicked nothing happens until the user refreshes the page.

```
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top auto " >
    <div class = "container">

    <a href = "index.html" class = "navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>

    <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- dropdown navbar for mobile -->
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse auto ">

                        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right auto">

                            <li ><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>


                               <li class = "dropdown">
                             <a href = "Menu.html" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" class = "active">Menu<b class = "caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a id ="menudrp" href = "Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a id= "indianstartersdrp" href = "#Indian-Starters">Indian Starters</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Mexican-Starters">Mexican Starters</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Thai-Starters">Thai Starters</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Indian-Main">Indian Main</a></li>                                                              
                                    <li><a href = "#Mexican-Main">Mexican Main</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Thai-Main">Thai Main</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Indian-Desserts">Indian Desserts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Mexican-Desserts">Mexican Desserts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Thai-Desserts">Thai Desserts</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                 </li>                     


                            <li class = "dropdown">
                             <a href = "Events.html" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Events<b class = "caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href = "Events.html#corporate">Corporate Events Catering</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "Events.html#wedding">Wedding Events Catering </a></li>
                                </ul>
                                 </li>

                            <li><a href = "gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li class = "dropdown">

                                <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href = "#">Twitter</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#">Facebook</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#">Google+</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#">Instagram</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href = "AboutUs.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```